# Cómo ejecutar acciones del metodo on(change, sin cambiar manualmente el valor

Tags: jquery

Tengo un select con varias opciones. Cuando se selecciona una opción, se ejecutan varias acciones (se cargan valores en input text, se cambian valores en otros select, etc). Esto lo controlo con:

```
$(document).on('change', '.select', function () 
            {
```

Después de que se seleccionó la opción y se ejecutaron las acciones, el usuario graba en la BD el valor seleccionado.

El problema que tengo es que cuando cargo desde la BD el valor del select almacenado y lo pongo en el select, no se ejecutan ninguna de las acciones, tal como lo hacía al principio cuando el usuario seleccionó la opción.  Supongo que esto es porque cuando el valor recuperado de la BD se carga  en el select no se verifica el método "change", por eso no se disparan las acciones.

La pregunta es saber si existe un método que permita que se ejecuten las acciones al setear en el select, el valor almacenado en la BD.

Comment: Podrías intentar con la función each de jQuery.

Comment: Cuando cargues el valor ejecuta
$(document).trigger('change');

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery` provee el método [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), el cual ejecuta todos los controladores y eventos asociados a los elementos coincidentes para el tipo de evento dado.

Ejemplo de uso:

```js
$(function() {
  var $res = $('#resultado'),
      $select = $('#select');
 
  function mostrarOpcionSeleccionada() {
    var $option = $select.find('option:selected');
    
    $('#resultado').text($option.text() + ' (' + $option.val() + ')');
  }

  $select.on('change', mostrarOpcionSeleccionada);
  
  // 
  $select.trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<select id="select">
  <option> - </option>
  <option value="1">Uno</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Dos</option>
</select><br/>
Opción seleccionada: <span id="resultado"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Propongo que hagas esto:

```
    $(document).on('change', '.select', function () 
    {
        f(); // Aquí está toda tu lógica
    });
```

Y luego, cuando quieras hacer todo lo que está dentro del evento change del componente select, simplemente llames a la función f()